# Formas de remover com SparseArray

Tags: java, android, estrutura-de-dados

Ao tentar remover itens de meu `SparsArray` encontrei o método `remove` e um  outro método que é o `removeAt` mas qual a diferença?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, o `remove`é apena um alias para `delete`. Então nós devamos comparar:

**`delete` vs `removeAt`**

E não há muita diferença. A única diferença é que o `delete` faz uma verificação da chave com `binarySearch`antes de atribuir o Objeto vazio ao valor da chave.

```
mValues[i] = DELETED;
```

Esse `DELETED` é um atributo que contém um Objeto vazio. Esse objeto é o que substitui valor a ser deletado.

**delete()**

```
public void delete(int key) { 
        int i = ContainerHelpers.binarySearch(mKeys, mSize, key); 

        if (i >= 0) { 
            if (mValues[i] != DELETED) { 
                mValues[i] = DELETED; 
                mGarbage = true; 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

**removeAt()**

```
public void removeAt(int index) { 
        if (mValues[index] != DELETED) { 
            mValues[index] = DELETED; 
            mGarbage = true; 
        } 
    }
```

**Qual eu devo usar?**

Se você tem CERTEZA que a chave que for informada sempre irá existir, use o `removeAt`.
Caso o contrário use o `remove` ou `delete`.

Para consultas: **[SparseArray](https://zgrepcode.com/android/9.0.0/base.core/android/util/sparsearray.java)**, **[Documentação do Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray)**

Comment: Então uma seria a remoção da chave e o outro remoção do conteúdo do `SparseArray` é isso ?

Comment: @RicardoLucas não... Ambos removem o objeto a partir da chave informada. A diferença é que um verifica se a chave existe e o outro não.

Comment: @RicardoLucas coloquei o link da classe para consulta.